# getting C error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hey I am getting this error:

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct value_t value;

struct value{
   void* x;
   int y;
   value* next;
   value* prev;
};

typedef struct key_t key;

struct key{
   int x;
   value * values;
   key* next;
   key* prev;
};
```

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
struct key new_node = (struct key) calloc(1, sizeof(struct key));
struct key* curr_node = head;

new_node.key = new_key;

struct value head_value = (struct value) calloc(1, sizeof(struct value))
```

Am I not suppose to use calloc on structs?  Also, I have a struct that I have created and then I want to set that to a pointer of that same struct type but getting an error.  This is an example of what I am doing:

```
struct value x;
struct value* y = *x;
```

this gives me this error

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
```

When I do y = x, I get this warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to assign a pointer expression (the return type of [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and friends is `void*`) to a struct type (`struct new_node`). That is nonsense. Also: the cast is not needed (and possibly dangerous, since it can hide errors)

```
struct key *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
```

the same problem with the other malloc() line:

```
struct value *head_value = calloc(1, sizeof *head_value);
```

More errors: You are omitting the 'struct' keyword (which is allowed in C++, but nonsense in C):

```
struct key{
   int x;
   struct value *values;
   struct key *next;
   struct key *prev;
};
```

UPDATE: using structs and pointers to struct.

```
struct key the_struct;
struct key other_struct;
struct key *the_pointer;

the_pointer = &other_struct; // a pointer should point to something

the_struct.x = 42;
the_pointer->x = the_struct.x; 

 /* a->b can be seen as shorthand for (*a).b :: */
(*thepointer).x = the_struct.x;

/* and for the pointer members :: */

the_struct.next = the_pointer;
the_pointer->next = malloc (sizeof *the_pointer->next);
```

Comment: a pointer type IS a scalar type. It's the structure type which is not a scalar type (structure types are of aggregate type).

Comment: Oops. My bad. What should I call it than? object? too confusing, IMHO. Pointer versus non-pointer seems more adequate.

Comment: If I just wanted a struct, could I just do "struct key new_node;" and not have to allocate the memory?  or do I have to allocate the memory first?

Comment: @user972276: `struct key new_node;` allocates the memory on the stack so you don't have to manage it by hand.

Comment: `struct key new_node;` is Ok, **but**: it allocates an automatic variable ("on the stack") which will get out of scope ("becomes invalid") once the function returns. (thus: you cannot return a pointer to it, because the object ceases to exist once the function returns)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Also, if I had a pointer to a struct, how do I reference the variables in the struct?  I tried something like new_node.value but that doesnt work.

Comment: I'll add that to the response.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you've correctly understood `typedef`s.

The common idiom with using typedefs for convenience naming is this:

```
struct foo {
    int something;
};

typedef struct foo foo_t;
```

Then you use the type `foo_t` instead of the less convenient `struct foo`.

For convenience, you can combine the struct declaration and the `typedef` into one block:

```
typedef struct {
    int something;
} foo_t;
```

This defines a `foo_t` just like the above.

The *last* token on the `typedef` line is the name you're assigning. I have no idea what the code you wrote is actually doing to your namespace, but I doubt it's what you want.

Now, as for the code itself: `calloc` returns a pointer, which means **both** your cast and your storage type should be `struct key*` (or, if you fix your naming, `key_t`). The correct line is `struct key* new_node = (struct key*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct key));`

For your second, independent, issue, the last line should be `struct value* y = &x;`. You want `y` to store the *address of* `x`, not the *thing at address x*. The error message indicates this - you are misusing the unary star operator to attempt to dereference a non-pointer variable.

Comment: Please don't throw in typedefs yet. The poor guy is already confused beyond understanding. Ooops sorry: the OP started it. I overlooked it.

Comment: +1, except that you shouldn't name types ending with `_t` because POSIX reserves these. It'll be alright for your own code and for small apps but any code destined for distribution or portability should avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct key new_node = (struct key) calloc(1, sizeof(struct key));
```

`calloc` returns a pointer value (`void *`), which you are trying to convert and assign to an aggregate (IOW, non-scalar) type (`struct key`).  To fix this, change the type of `new_node` to `struct key *` and rewrite your allocation as follows:

```
struct key *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
```

Two things to note.  First of all, ditch the cast expression.  `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all return `void *`, which can be assigned to any object pointer type without need for a cast<sup>1</sup>.  In fact, the presence of a cast can potentially mask an error if you forget to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise don't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope<sup>2</sup>.

Secondly, note that I use the expression `*new_node` as the argument to `sizeof`, rather than `(struct key)`.  `sizeof` doesn't evaluate it's operator (unless it's a variable array type, which this isn't); it just computes the type of the expression.  Since the type of the expression `*new_node` is `struct key`, `sizeof` will return the correct number of bytes to store that object.  It can save some maintenance headaches if your code is structured like

```
T *foo;
... // more than a few lines of code
foo = malloc(sizeof (T))
```

and you change the type of `foo` in the declaration, but forget to update the `malloc` call.

Also, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with your typedefs and struct definitions.  The code

```
typedef struct value_t value;  

struct value{
   void* x;
   int y;
   value* next;
   value* prev;
};
```

isn't doing what you think it is.  You're creating a typedef name `value` which is a synonym for an as-yet-undefined type `struct value_t`.  This `value` type is different from the `struct value` type you create later (typedef names and struct tags live in different namespaces).  Rewrite your structs to follow this model:

```
struct value_t {
  void *x;
  int y;
  struct value_t *next;
  struct value_t *prev;
};

typedef struct value_t value;
```

Also, life will be easier if you write your declarations so that the `*` is associated with the declarator, not the type specifier<sup>3</sup>.  A declaration like `T* p` is parsed as though it were written `T (*p)`.  This will save you the embarrassment of writing `int* a, b;` and expecting both `a` and `b` to be pointers (`b` is just a regular `int`).

---

<sup>1</sup> - This is one area where C and C++ differ; C++ does *not* allow implicit conversions between `void *` and other object pointer types, so if you compile this as C++ code, you'll get an error at compile time.  Also, before the 1989 standard was adopted, the `*alloc` functions returned `char *`, so in those days a cast *was* required if you were assigning to a different pointer type.  This should only be an issue if you're working on a *very old* system.

<sup>2</sup>  - Up until the 1999 standard, if the compiler saw a function call without a preceding declaration, it assumed the function returned an `int` (which is why you still occasionally see examples like

```
 main()
 {
   ...
 }
```

in some tutorials; `main` is *implicitly* typed to return `int`. As of C99, this is no longer allowed).  So if you forget to include `stdlib.h` and call `calloc` (and you're not compiling as C99), the compiler will assume the function returns an `int` and generate the machine code accordingly.  If you leave the cast off, the compiler will issue a diagnostic to the effect that you're trying to assign an `int` value to a pointer, which is not allowed. If you leave the cast in, the code will compile but the pointer value may be munged at runtime (conversions of pointers to `int` and back to pointers again is not guaranteed to be meaningful).

<sup>3</sup> - There are some rare instances, limited to C++, where the `T* p` style can make code a little more clear, but in general you're better off following the `T *p` style.  Yes, that's a personal opinion, but one that's backed up by a non-trivial amount of experience.

Answer (score 1):

[`calloc`(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) returns a [**pointer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) to the memory it allocates.

```
struct key new_node = (struct key) calloc(1, sizeof(struct key));
```

should be

```
struct key* new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct key));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign a pointer to a non-pointer variable. Change new_node to be a pointer.

Also, to use the address of variable, you need `&`, not `*`, so change it to `struct value* y = &x;`

Edit: your typedefs are wrong too. reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, you want to use an ampersand `&` instead of an astrisk "*`.  An astrisk dereferences a pointer, an ampersand gives you the pointer from the value.

Comment: @user972276 this is the section I was talking about:
struct value* y = *x;
should be:
struct value * y = &x;